# Programming a geoweb application for cloud. What does it imply?

Tags: postgis, cloud-gis

I've recently started to develop a geoweb application using GeoDjango + PostGIS in the backend, HTML5 + JS in the frontend. I'm really at the beginning, so, I have time to change a lot of things.

Basically, I want to store raster/vector data, allow some basic operations over them and visualize the result. Simplified, translate the concept of a Desktop GIS (QGIS, OpenJUMP...) to the web

My big issue right now is I'd like to operate over a cloud infrastructure, but I'm not sure of the implications from a developer point of view. I'm learning about the concept "Dev-Ops", and I've read some articles, like [this](http://www.itworld.com/print/121228), but I'm afraid of doing things wrong, because I never built an application specially conceived to be deployed in a Cloud infrastructure before. And I don't want to incur in an "analysis paralysis" situation.

For example, should I first care about installing PostGIS in a Cloud infrastructure and test how to scale it?

I think my problem is I don't know what kind of things are pure "developer things" and what kind of things are "enviroment configuration". And how to mix them. What comes first, what comes next, etc.

Any advice is welcome. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: i have the same questions as you in this post.Im trying to use Postgis in the backend and HTML5 + JS in the frontend. Ive seen there have been some months since your post without success, so if you have more experience know i would appreciate any advice, indication, link that could help...thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Google offers some nice tools. Check out google drive, fusion tables and shpescape.com (one of several sites that lets you import gis shapefiles directly to fusion tables)

There's a whole api built around this so you won't have to roll any of the client/server stuff yourself and I am only guessing, but i'd imagine being a google tool that it scales.